# CodeIgniter PHP Mailer Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
     $MSG = "Dear " . $student['firstname'] . " " . $student['lastname'] . ", " . $student['class'] . " " . $student['section'] . " your userid & pass for school SIS is " . $student['username'] . " & " . $student['password'] . " Login at: " . $stu_setting['short_url'] . ", Welcome to " . $stu_setting['name'] . ".";
    $skool = "Welcome to " . $stu_setting['name'] . " SIS";
    $to_email = 'support@digitave.com';
     $this->CI->email->from('noreply@digi-sis.org'); 
     $this->CI->email->to($to_email);
     $this->CI->email->subject($skool); 
     $this->CI->email->message($MSG);    
     $this->CI->email->send();
```

using https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer for sending Email in CI, but whenever i am trying to send an email it changes the variables values in random mixed characters. but it loads $MSG correctly.

Mail Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wDkm.png

Comment: $to_email doesn't works when i am using $to_email 
 = $student['email']

Comment: changed crlf value to \r\n it solved half of my problem but subject still appears with equal to signs

Comment: Codeigniter has a built in email library https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 1):

Changing **crlf** to **\r\n** and setting **charset UTF-8** solved the problem.